# Not serializable error with Redux Toolkit and Redux persist

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

I don't understand why this error is triggered even though my `UserDataState` contains only plain js objects. I've read that disabling the serializing checks could be an option but it doesn't seem right to me.

> A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path:
> `register`. Value:  function register(key)  Take a look at the logic
> that dispatched this action:   Object { type: "persist/PERSIST",
> register: register(key), rehydrate: rehydrate(key, payload, err)  }
> (See
> [https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string…t-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants](https://redux.js.org/faq/actions#why-should-type-be-a-string%E2%80%A6t-least-serializable-why-should-my-action-types-be-constants))
> (To allow non-serializable values see:
> https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#working-with-non-serializable-data)

UserSlice.ts

```js
interface UserDataState {
  userData: {
    id: string | null;
    createdAt: string | null;
    updatedAt: string | null;
    email: string | null;
    firstName: string | null;
    lastName: string | null;
    username: string | null;
    profilePicture: string | null;
    gamesPlayed: number | null;
    gamesWon: number | null;
    userPoints: number | null;
    userLevel: number | null;
    isOnline: boolean | null;
    currentRoom: string | null;
  }
}
```

Store.ts

```js
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  channels: ChannelSlice,
  user: persistReducer({ key: "user", storage }, userReducer),
})

const rootReducer: Reducer = (state: RootState, action: AnyAction) => {
  if (action.type === "user/unsetUser") {
    storage.removeItem('persist:user')

    return appReducer(undefined, action)
  }
  return appReducer(state, action)
}

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
})
```

Here's my raw data in redux:

```js
{
  channels: {
    activeChannel: null,
    visibleChannels: []
  },
  user: {
    userData: {
      id: null,
      createdAt: null,
      updatedAt: null,
      email: null,
      firstName: null,
      lastName: null,
      username: null,
      profilePicture: null,
      gamesPlayed: null,
      gamesWon: null,
      userPoints: null,
      userLevel: null,
      isOnline: null,
      currentRoom: null
    },
    _persist: {
      version: -1,
      rehydrated: true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to ***completely*** turn off the serializable checks, but you'll want to ignore some of the specific actions that use non-serializable payloads.

See the [Use with Redux-Persist](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist) and [Serializability Middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/serializabilityMiddleware) documentation for complete details.

Example:

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import {
  ...,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from 'redux-persist';

const reduxPersistActions = [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER];

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [...reduxPersistActions],
      },
    }),
});
```

Comment: Thank you! But don't you find this weird that it gives me this error?

Comment: @Jules No, not really, once you understand what it means. I was also a bit caught off-guard when I upgraded to using Redux-Toolkit (RTK) and Redux-Persist, but Redux-Persist predates RTK that includes the default opinionated middlewares, so IMO it doesn't *not* make sense. Also, IIRC this is just a warning, not an actual error.